how to distinguish front-end ts-config from Deno default typescript checker
i'm trying to migrate my project from nodeJS to Deno. it has 2 part:

the part that run on server to build, serve and test front-end app
the front-end part in /app directory that will be build by rollup or webpack.

I rewrite the first part with typescript and everything works fine but the problem is deno wants me to change my front-end code ts file according to deno ts config for examle adding .ts in the end of each dependancy import or it cant understand some of my module import like importing css file or html file.
so I just want to tell deno to stop checking src/**/* folders and files and let a front-end typescript tsconfig.json in the src folder check this folder so i just add 'tsconfig.json' in the src folder and add "exclude": ["src/"] to deno.json.
the problem is if  I add exclude to deno.json no typescript compiler check the front-end code in vscode. but i want normal old tsc check this folder ts file. do you guys have any solution for this?

What you are looking for is to partially enable Deno for a workspace.
In your settings.json remove deno.enable: true (if set) and add the following:
"deno.enablePaths": [ "./your-deno-code" ]

A 'multi-root workspace' would be another (more difficult) option.

Docs:

Partially Deno enabling a workspace: https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/references/vscode_deno/#partially-deno-enabling-a-workspace
Workspace Folders: https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/references/vscode_deno/#workspace-folders

